# Find the value of a,b&c

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I want to find the values of A, B and C.

> Find the values of $a, b$ and $c$:
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> 6xa+b&=&28 \\
> 4a&=&3xc
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$

Could someone please help to find the solution for the above problem?

Comment: you have two equations and three unknowns?

Comment: capital and small letters are generally different variables.  Pick one variable you want to be anything and you can compute the other two.

Comment: Do the values have to be integers?

Comment: Substuiting a=3 & c=4 solves the problem. It's not the right approach as we can substitute negative integers or fractions as well.